# show a div after a html form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am showing up a hidden div which has a textbox using a javascript assigned to a html button. My requirement is

a - keep user entered data in textbox after form submit - able to do it

b - If user added the second hidden div using `+ Show another` button and once form submit, I would like to display that textbox along with data - able to keep the data but div not displaying (going to hidden state  )

**my html code**:

```
<form  id="main" name="main" action="#text" method="post" > 
    <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa1">
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="collect-fa1" name="collect-fa1" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['collect-fa1'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['collect-fa1']); }?>" /></span> </div>                  
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="collect-fa2" name="collect-fa2" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['collect-fa2'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['collect-fa2']); }?>" /></span> </div>                  
    </div>

    <div class="add_remove_column">
    <input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="2" readonly>
    <button type="button" onClick="AddNewColumn();" id="addfa" > + Show another  </button>
    </div>


<input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="create my symcli script" />

</form>
```

and javascript to show the hidden div once I click `+ Show another`

```
function AddNewColumn() 
    {
        var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),3) ;
        if( facount < 3)
            {
                facount = facount+1;

                for(i=1;i<3;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast");                 
                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount);  

            }
}
```

Comment: Where does the form go when you hit submit. To a server or??

Comment: during  form data will be collected and display it along with other data on another html page

Comment: Ok, sorry, i just realised the php tag. Can you not use php to show the div after form submit, why do you want to do this in JS?

Comment: What does mean `display that textbox along with data`? You mean you want to post data along with other data?

Comment: @MahanGM :     yes.. I figured out this `style="<?php if(empty($_POST['collect-fa2'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>` will give the output which i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out and blow code helped me to resolve this

```
<div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa2" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['collect-fa2'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>" >
```